# Recorrer valores de un diccionario uno por uno

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo este problema y no se como resolverlo.
He creado un serializer en el cual tengo frutas y colores, en la parte del views he declarado algunos valores de ejemplo. El problema viene al momento de mostrarlo en la vista, ya que me muestra todos los valores juntos y no me de uno en uno.

serializers.py

class frutasSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

```
frutas= serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
colores = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

class frutasView(views.APIView):

```
def get(self, request):
    f=['platano','manzana','pera']
    c=['amarillo','rojo','verde']
    yourdata = [{
        "fruta": f,
         "color": c,
        }]
    results = serviciosSerializer(yourdata, many=True).data
    return Response(results)

"""RESULTADO:

"fruta":['platano','manzana','pera']

"color"=['amarillo','rojo','verde']


RESULTADO ESPERADO:

"fruta":"platano",

"color":"amarillo",


"fruta":"manzana",

"color":"rojo","""
```

.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sale es lo esperable, ya que eso es exactamente lo que estás construyendo con esta línea:

```py
    yourdata = [{
        "fruta": f,
         "color": c,
        }]
```

puesto que tanto `f` como `c` son listas, el diccionario que estás construyendo tiene en su clave `"fruta"` la lista de frutas, y en su clave `"color"` la lista de colores. Además, la lista que finalmente retornas (lo que está englobado por `[ ]` contiene un único diccionario.

Entiendo que lo que querías era crear una lista con varios diccionarios, cada uno de los cuales contendría una sola fruta y un solo color.

Esto puede construirse de forma muy compacta haciendo uso de una *list comprehension* y de la función `zip()`, así:

```
yourdata = [ {"fruta": fruta, "color": color} for fruta, color in zip(f,c) ]
```

### Explicación

`zip()` es una función que recibe varios iterables (en este caso las listas `f` y `c`) y te devuelve otro iterable que va avanzando por ambos a la vez. Cada vez que iteras sobre el resultado devuelto por `zip()` obtienes una tupla cuyo primer elemento está tomado de la primera lista (`f`) y el segundo de la segunda (`c`). En este caso, cada iteración devuelve por tanto una fruta y un color.

Mediante la expresión generadora `for fruta, color in zip(...)` vamos recogiendo esos dos valores que retorna `zip()` y guardándolos en un par de variables que he llamado `fruta` y `color`.

La expresión `{"fruta": fruta, "color": color}` crea un diccionario con esos valores. La *list comprehension* completa va creando una lista con los diccionarios resultantes.

En realidad, toda esa expresión no es sino una forma más compacta de escribir el siguiente bucle:

```
yourdata = []
for fruta, color in zip(f, c):
   yourdata.append({"fruta": fruta, "color": color})
```

El resultado sería el mismo, por lo que puedes usar la sintaxis que te resulte más fácil de leer.